# Cannot connect to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi

Could you help me with some erorr in Power BI. When i tried to connect GA, I had this erorr:

> DataSource.Error: There was a temporary error.
>   Please try again later.
>   DataSourceKind=GoogleAnalytics
>   DataSourcePath=GoogleAnalytics
>   error=Record

Could you get me some advice how fix it?

Comment: Can you confirm that using the same GA connection works correctly in (for example) Google Data Studio?

Comment: Hi! It was some troubels in GA, now it work.